# ballerina JDBC error Failed to get driver instance No suitable driver

Tags: java, jdbc, ballerina

I have a simple Ballerina application that i need to talk with a database through a JDBC driver.

I get a runtime error that says:

`error: Error in SQL connector configuration: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=xxxxx Caused by :No suitable driver`

My Ballerina.toml contains the following:

```
[package]
org = "myname"
name = "data_service"
version = "0.1.0"
distribution = "2201.4.0"

[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true

[[platform.java11.dependency]]
path = "./interclient.jar"
```

I know the **interclient.jar** works, because i am using it in the DBSchema application ( database client ) to connect to my Database ( Embarcadero Interbase ). And i am able to actually see the tables, run queries etc.

But when trying to use that same jar ( interclient.jar ) in my Ballerina application to talk through JDBC I get the above error.

Not sure if I am not properly using it ( in Ballerina.toml ) or what.

Here is my application code:

```
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;
import ballerina/sql;
import ballerina/io;

public type User record {|
    int id?;
    string name;
    string username;
    string email;
    int? client_id;
|};

configurable string USER = ?;
configurable string PASSWORD = ?;
configurable string HOST = ?;
configurable int PORT = ?;
configurable string DATABASE = ?;


final jdbc:Client dbClient = check new (
    url=HOST, user=USER, password=PASSWORD
);

isolated function getUser(int id) returns error? {
    sql:ParameterizedQuery query = `select * from USERS where ID = 1`;
    stream<User, sql:Error?> resultStream = dbClient->query(query);
    
    // Iterating the returned table.
    check from record{} student in resultStream
    do {
        // Can perform operations using the record 'student'.
        io:println("Student name: ", student.name);
    }; 
    return;  
}
```

Application compiles ok, no warnings or errors.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you try to specify `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` of the dependency as well?
Refer to the link below. https://ballerina.io/learn/manage-dependencies/#specify-a-local-jar-file-path

Comment: Hello Anupama Pathirage,

I've added this to my Ballerina.toml:

`[[platform.java11.dependency]]
groupId = "jdbc.interbase"
artifactId = "interclient"
version = "13.2.0"
path = "./interclient.jar"
`

Still the same run time error

Thanks!